# How do I know if my site-to-site vpn connection is being saturated?

Tags: networking, cisco, network-monitoring, site-to-site-vpn

We've got a T1-internet connection with a Cisco ASA 5510 appliance in our small office.

We have a site-to-site vpn connection from our office to a remote data center.

Question(s):

1. How can I find out if my site-to-site vpn traffic is being saturated via the Cisco ADSM?
2. Are there other simple/free tools that can show me if my site-to-site vpn connection is being saturated?

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back and needed to see what sort of speed the VPN tunnel was running at, the good folks here suggested  and it worked a treat. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf

Comment: As you know how fast the link can potentially go (T1) you can monitor the current through put via SNMP with something like Cacti, and test it for max throughput with iPerf as dannymcc mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the Cisco ASA 5510 has NetFlow support built into it which should supply the statistics that you're looking for. There's an article on configuring NetFlow on the ASA [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-6113#ASDM).

With regards to part 2 of your question, I've had some good results using [SolarWinds NetFlow Analyzer](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/netflow-analyzer.aspx) with sFlow rather than NetFlow, but the results should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use SNMP to poll the interface for the traffic throughput information.

Two free options for this are, If your ok with Linux have a look at Cacti, Or on windows have a look at PRTG as there is a free version if your only polling a few interfaces.